# ‘The turkey won’t fully cook’ needs to use passive voice?

Tags: grammar, tense, passive-voice

I found this sentence in an English leaning material:

> The temperature needs to be 220 at the minimum or else the turkey **won’t fully cook**.

The subject of the latter half is ‘turkey’. Do we need to use passive voice in here:

> or else the turkey **won’t be fully cooked**?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't need to.  Both versions are OK, I think, although I would prefer the original.    If we say *be fully cooked* we are describing the (end) state of the turkey, whereas *fully cook* focuses on the process of cooking.

It is acceptable to use the verb *cook* intransitively, that is "the turkey cooks", rather than "the oven cooks the turkey".  Likewise we can say the water boils, the cake rises, the soup thickens, the glazing browns, rather than having to say the heat boils the water, the heat thickens the soup, etc.

Comment: _The cake rises_ is a different case, because _rise_ cannot be transitive (at least, in my version of English). There is a causitive _raise_; but it is not used in this sense: we can't say _The oven raised the cake_, "self-raising flour" notwithstanding.